# Apache PHP localhost changes response too slow

Tags: php, apache, localhost, response

In my PHP localhost project, If I change something in my code [e.x: echo a line] and refresh my browser the changes **did not show immediately**. I have to **wait** for 10-15 seconds and refresh my browser then it shows the changes. I tried on different browsers.

Note: I'm just using the apache server. And I don't have any error to start and stop the apache server.

Comment: It may be browser caching. You should disable the cache when you're debugging.

Comment: Maybe something with cache in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably the browser's cache. And the browser checks for updates in the website's pages every 10-15 secs, or precisely if its been an amount of time since the last cache, it rechecks if the cache is up to date, so it updates there.

See [HTTP Cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching).

You can stop it by adding:

```
Header always set Cache-Control "no-cache"
Header always set Pragma "no-cache"
```

But, cache can really improve the user page load speed for static content. So, think more about this before setting this in a production server.

You should usually always disable cache on development servers.